# Flutter - How to implement a bottom navigation bar with named routes?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I wanted to implement a bottom navigation bar with named routes. It seems the view keeps refreshing, getting stuck and when I tap the bottom navigation tabs, they are not working with my code.

```
final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  int currentIndex = 0;
  List<String> _pages = <String>[
    Routes.startupViewRoute,
    Routes.startupViewRoute,
    Routes.startupViewRoute,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Navigator(
        key: _navigatorKey,
        initialRoute: Routes.startupViewRoute,
        onGenerateRoute: Router().onGenerateRoute,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          _navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(_pages[index]);
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
            title: new Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.person),
            title: new Text('Profile'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: Text('Settings'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely using Route name is more comfortable.
it has few steps.
1. at the screen you want to navigate to add a final variable that hold the route for ex.
static const routeName = '/pageName'; (the / is important)

2. at the main page you need to add:
   PageName.routeName:(ctx)=>PageName(),
3. where you want to redirect to the new page add:
   Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(PageName.routeName);
   you can also pass argument through it.

Comment: Did you get this working, looking for an example

Comment: That is a general approach which is right. Although with `bottomNavigationBar` it might refresh current view on `.pushNamed()` instead of routing.